# HTTPHandler Processrequest() is not getting invoked from .cs file

Tags: c#

I am using HTTPHandler to upload files. And i'm using below code to call .ashx file and i set a breakpoint in handler its not hitting the breakpoint.

```
 private void UploadFile(HttpPostedFile uPostedFile)
{
    UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder(Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, Request.Url.Port,ResolveUrl("FileUploadHandler.ashx"));
    ub.Query = string.Format("filename={0}", uPostedFile.FileName);
    var data = uPostedFile.InputStream;

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ub.Uri);
    request.Method = "POST";
    data.CopyTo(request.GetRequestStream());
    request.BeginGetResponse(DataUploadCompleted, request);
}


 private void DataUploadCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
 {
     var request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
     var response = request.EndGetResponse(ar);
     //some code
 }
```

But if i browse .ashx file Processrequest() getting executed. 
Please let me know if anything i'm missing in code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the break point in DataUploadCompleted method. Are you getting response? If yes then check which kind of response it is. It may help resolving your issue.

Comment: hi nitin, Thank you for your immediate response. I placed break point in DataUploadCompleted method. But its not even hitting the method. Once executing the upload file method its displaying upload document page in site. Nothing happening.

Comment: Does it executes UploadFile method completely? Try enabling Throw CLR runtime exceptions. Go to Debug>>Exceptions, In exceptions windows check both the checkboxes for Common Language Runtime Exception. Now it will throw any CLR runtime exception and probably you would get more details from that.